# Randomly select hour from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, random

I have a hard time to randomly select rows from a dataframe. In general, choosing one row is not a problem using `np.random.choice(data,size=1000)`. I assume that replacement=True. However, I need to randomly select an hour and as output, recieve the 4 rows of each quarter.

The dataframe to choose from is the following (1132 rows):

```
data=
                     Price  Consume    Feed
StartTime                                  
2018-07-04 02:00:00  45.80    67.91   67.91
2018-07-04 02:15:00  45.80    51.05   51.05
2018-07-04 02:30:00  45.80    46.12   46.12
2018-07-04 02:45:00  45.80    46.86   46.86
2018-07-11 05:00:00  43.80    43.49   43.49
2018-07-11 05:15:00  43.80    50.71   50.71
2018-07-11 05:30:00  43.80    48.19   48.19
2018-07-11 05:45:00  43.80    40.02   40.02
```

My desired output is something like this:

Assuming the random generator has "selected" `2018-07-11 05:00:00`, the output would be

```
2018-07-11 05:00:00  43.80    43.49   43.49
2018-07-11 05:15:00  43.80    50.71   50.71
2018-07-11 05:30:00  43.80    48.19   48.19
2018-07-11 05:45:00  43.80    40.02   40.02
```

Depending on the number (N) of random samples, the length of the resulting dataframe should be 4xN.

Is it possible to randomly select an dayhour directly from the dataframe and repeat this 1000 times? I am afraid that using an extra dataframe to select an hour and then looking the corresponding values up in the original dataframe will be too time consuming. 
I am confident that this should be doable in Python, but I couldn`t find any tips on this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you compare values with [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) for remove minutes and seconds:

```
N = 1000
vals = pd.to_datetime(np.random.choice(df.index,size=N)).floor('H')
hours = df.index.floor('H')

for i in vals:
    print (df[hours == i])
```

EDIT: For join all small DataFrames use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = pd.concat([df[hours == i] for i in vals])
```

Or create array with `np.concatenate` of `DatetimeIndex` and select by `loc`:

```
idx = np.concatenate([df.index[hours == i] for i in vals])
df1 = df.loc[idx]
```

Comment: Yes, I think this in the right direction. I notice, that I have been a little unclear, because the final dataframe should contain, in case of N=1000 4000 rows. Your suggestion creates N dataframes of length 4. How would I have to adapt the code?

Answer (score 1):

Sample once to get a random index, then find all matches to that date and hour:

```
random_idx = df.sample().index
df[(df.index.date == random_idx.date) & (list(df.index.hour) == random_idx.hour)]
```

Then to do it 1000 times:

```
for i in range(1000):
    random_idx = df.sample().index
    print(df[(df.index.date == random_idx.date) & (list(df.index.hour) == random_idx.hour)])
```